# В БД из php передаются пустые значения

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

При запросе к БД, в неё передаются пустые значения, вместо указанных в запросе.
Если тот же запрос выполнить через SQL в PhpMyAdmin, то строки заполняются нужными значениями. В чём ошибка?

```
    <?php
    $con= mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'testsite2');
    mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8');
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo 'Error: '. mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $query="INSERT INTO news_category(id, name, description)
            VALUES(NULL, 'Спорт', 'Спортивное обозрение'),(NULL, 'Развлечения', 'Ток-шоу');";
    echo $query;


    $info=mysqli_query($con, $query);
    if(!$info){
        echo 'Error';
    }

   ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Не передавались только кириллические значения. Если вставить значения на латинице, то всё ок. Проблема с кодировками.